# What should be size of Document in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, best-practice

I have downloaded Adobe Illustrator 2017. It has different options for Mobile, Web, Print, File Video, Art Illustration.

I have to redraw a logo in illustrator which I have already designed in Adobe Photoshop. Actually, customer wants generic high resolution image which he can use for printing business cards, printing on portfolio, posted on web or mobile devices and then to be printed on Board (Bill Board outside his Showroom). I want to know what should be the exact option and size (Height, Width, Bleed) of document so that all his needs can be catered in one image without loosing quality in resizing. A bigger image will be resized in smaller image for printing on business cards and smaller image will need to resized in larger image to be printing on Board.

Currently, Adobe Photoshop designed logo (.png) can only be used on website. The logo I designed in Adobe Photoshop is of (340 pixel * 340 Pixel) 72 Resolution and RGB Document. I have also attached the already designed logo which I should redraw in Adobe Illustrator.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are making a Vector-based logo, therefore the size that you design it to is pretty much irrelevant, as whoever does the layouts for cards, latter heads etc etc will scale it as necessary.

Personally I would design it on a document sized to 1000x1000px

Some things to watch out for though are drop-shadows and stroke(line) widths which do not scale as they are set at a pixel/point size.